# How to find the declaration of a view/action in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, declaration

I'm new to ASP.NET.
I have a web project in which every View or Action name are underline as you can see in the image (Sorry but it takes at least 10 reputations to post image).

[Image](http://1drv.ms/1r34CCG)

It contains 2 declarations, the first one is the default: ViewResult Controller.View().. like normal. And the second one is the View file or the action that it refers to.
When you use Go to Declaration command, it'll bring you to that file or that action. That's what I want, but I don't know how to get it. I have Resharper installed and using Visual studio 2013. I have tried to create new project but it just show only the default declaration. I get this project from a private source and the one who give me have no idea about it.
Please help me if you know. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Resharper then just Right click On underlined text and select Go to Declaration or Go to Implementation. It will take to you view file.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but it just take me to the source code, for exp, if I click on the View() method it come to the method "protected internal ViewResult View()" not the View file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but changing the default library System.Web.MVC from version 5.1.0.0 to version 4.0.0.0 have enabled that feature for me. But it'll need to change other references to downgrade the whole project to version 4.